# How to rerun a Vuex Getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Maybe I have misunderstood what a getter is in Vuex, but say I have a getter that gets the size of a DOM element, a div for example. I would do something like this :

```
const getters = {
  getContainerWidth (state) {
    return document.getElementById('main-content').clientWidth;
  }
}
```

Now when I start my app, all the getters seem to be run straight away. What if the div isn't available at startup? How do I rerun a getter?

I run the getter like this at the moment :

```
import store from '@/store'
store.getters['myModule/getContainerWidth']
```

I thought maybe this would work :

```
store.getters['myModule/getContainerWidth']()
```

But since store.getters is an object containing properties and values, and the values not being functions, I can't rerun them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters should depend on `state` field to be reactive. It you want to observe `clientWidth` changes - it does not work.

If you want to use it like function then just return function from getter:

```
const getters = {
  getContainerWidth (state) {
    return () => {
       let container = document.getElementById('main-content');
       return container ? container.clientWidth : 0
    };
 }
```

}

and use it like `getContainerWidth()`